# RESTORE .bak-file from c:\users\ directories on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, restore, database-backups

I have this update tool for my program. The tool updates the SQL Server database with this code (vb and sql).

```
Dim sql As Process = Process.Start("sqlcmd.exe", Param + " -i update.sql -o log.txt")
```

`Param` contains the name of the `.bak` file `myprogram_update.bak` among others.

`update.sql` starts with

```
RESTORE DATABASE [myprogram_tmp] 
FROM DISK = N'$(db_src)' 
WITH FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'myprogram_tmp' TO @mdf,
MOVE N'myprogram_tmp_log' TO @ldf,
NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5
```

`@mdf` and `@ldf` are standard paths read from the SQL Server settings.

The update tool is shipped to customers and the problem is that usually SQL Servers aren't allowed to read in user directories of windows like `Desktop` or `Downloads`. But many customers unzip the archive to these directories and then they get this error.

> Could not access myprogram_update.bak / access denied.

I can't change the settings on every customers server, so is there any way to make it work for these directories? One idea of mine was to run a setup first and unzip it to `program files` but maybe there is a smarter solution.

Edit: the tool runs in administrator mode.

Comment: Consider shipping your changes and/or initial database as a DACPAC or BACPAC. Deploying that only requires permissions on SQL Server itself. Only a limited amount of data is supported this way, but it's more convenient than scripting restores (invoking the DACPAC deploy programmatically is supported through DacFx). Database projects in general are a big win, as they fully support versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now put my program into an setup which is usually installed under an ordinary folder, like `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram`. Here SQL-Server has access.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for elevation and run as an administrator account, maybe this will help:

http://www.downloadinformer.com/how-to-make-a-vb-net-application-always-run-in-administrator-mode/

Comment: The application runs already always with administrator mode. The update itself works fine, also the sql part with `UPDATE` or `ALTER`. But the `RESTORE` fails on `Desktop` but works in `c:\temp` for example.

Comment: No, this doesn't help - even an administrator cannot access a local user's disk drive from a remote SQL Server machine.